# How could have a loss/cost/error function that cannot be written as an average?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function

Check this phrase in this online book:
https://hyp.is/GsHrloyvEeaYQ093X053Wg/neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html

It refers that the quadratic cost function (RSS) can be written as an average for each individual training example.

so if the cost of a single training example is Cx = (1/2) * ||y-a||^2

you can have C = (1/n) * Σ(Cx)

Could you give an example of an error / cost function that cannot be written as an average?

Comment: The max, the min, the q'th percentile ... You didn't ask for it to be differentiable ;)

Comment: So a non-differentiable function would be an example?..

Comment: @GeorgePligor Emre isn't saying that *any* non-differentiable function would be an example; rather, they're saying that some non-differentiable functions (such as the ones they've listed) would suffice.

Comment: Emre's examples might make good metrics, but would not usually make practical loss functions. Generally you don't want aggregate functions *other* than simple linear sums/mean because they won't be differentiable (and technically taking the mean isn't necessary, it just scales things nicely so you don't need to adjust learning rate as much). Most ML algorithms rely on gradient-based optimisers, which limits choice.

Answer (score 1):

One example is KL divergence which quantifies the difference between actual and predicted densities:

$$CF = \sum P(x) log \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$